# The named parameter 'home' isn't defined Flutter

Tags: dart, flutter, flutter-layout

when I create my work I get this problem? The named parameter 'home' isn't defined.
I don t know why? 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nhlfx.jpg)

Comment: Please add the output of `flutter doctor`, `flutter analyze` and the code that causes the error.

Comment: Can you provide some code?

Comment: i deleted all my code cuz i was thinking the problem from me but i found the demo code with flutter has the same problem.

Comment: You need to share some link or code otherwise it is difficult to assist.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you instantiated a widget and then expected a named parameter 'home' as in

```
Scaffold(home: ...)
```

It seems you inserted the home parameter in function or constructor that does not expect it.
Please note that the constructor parameter home is special to the Scaffold class. Most other Widgets do not have it. 
To get  list of expected function (or constructor) parameters, move the textmarker inside the brackets and hit Ctrl + P (Macos: CMD+P)

Please be a bit more specific with your question next time. I really had to guess what you might have meant and gave my answer based on that. So my answer might ot might not answer your question. Thanks!

Comment: now when i open just the demo Flutter Project .. i found the same problem without touch anything ..